# How 70C 2Ah batteries can have XT60 connector if it rated only for 60A current and not 140A?

Tags: lipo-batteries, connectors

Can it fit higher currents than nominal? Is it safe?

Answer (score 2):

This is a difference in peak current and continuious current.

A [random XT60 supplier](https://www.gobilda.com/xt60-connector-pack-mh-fc-x-5-fh-mc-x-5/) from a web search quotes:

> Max Continuous Current: 60A
> Max Peak Current: 180A

(This supplier/manufacturer doesn't specify how long you can pull over 60A before it fails; this is likely a question of heat dissapation, which will vary slightly in each design and probably between XT60 manufacturers. But there are also usually limits on how long you can run a 70C battery at 70C discharge rate for similar reasons, so you will want to compare datasheets and pick complimentary parts.)